# How to add more than one view to single item in context menu in android?

Tags: android

i am new in android and trying to add more than one view(such as textview and checkbox) to single item in context menu for user to give some options.
.
.
please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there, please specify if the context menu is for a list or the main context menu?

Comment: i need for fragment !

Comment: in main activity.... !

Comment: Are you going to use an Icon or the standard Android menu button to show context menu?

Comment: i am using one textview and one custom checkbox to set on/off...thanks

Comment: I am asking what will you click to show context menu, not what you want in context menu

Comment: long press on fragment !

Answer (score 0):

Call method below

```
public void showPopUpMenu(Activity context, View anchor, int     menuResId, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener onMenuItemSelectedListener){
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, anchor);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(menuResId, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(onMenuItemSelectedListener);
        popup.show();
}
```

Comment: No problem Pradeep :)